# How to create a get_cartesian function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I am trying to figure out the code to program a function called get_cartesian.

Here is a screenshot of the problem I am looking to solve:

[Create get_cartesian function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpuyt.png)

Here is the question copied and pasted:

**Exercise 3: get_cartesian**

Example

The function get_cartesian does a cartesian product of an RDD with itself and returns an RDD with DISTINCT pairs of points.

Input: An RDD containing the given list of points

Output: An RDD containing The cartesian product of the RDD with itself

Example Code

```
test_rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,0), (2,0), (3,0)])
get_cartesian(test_rdd).collect()
Example Output
```

[((1, 0), (2, 0)), ((1, 0), (3, 0)), ((2, 0), (1, 0)), ((2, 0), (3, 0)), ((3, 0), (1, 0)), ((3, 0), (2, 0))]

I tried with code but it was not correct, and I'm stuck on how to go forward. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know much about Spark but [cartesian](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.cartesian) example shows that elements in tuples are not distinct, so you could use some kind of a filter:

```
def get_cartesian(rdd): 
    rdd  = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1])
    return rdd
```

Disclaimer: lambda used for `filter` might be wrong, let me know if it's fine!

Comment: It went through the first Unit Test just fine. There are 2 hidden ones but I cannot see them. As far as I can tell at this time, you did this correct. Thank you!